# How to use sympy.physics.quantum Commutator?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to work out some commutator manipulations and found this tool in sympy. It appears to work as expected (but the documentation is virtually non-existent or at least I found little, but see the comment by Dalton Bentley below), but I ran into the following problem.

```
from sympy.physics.quantum import Commutator as Comm
from sympy.physics.quantum import Operator
A = Operator('A')
B = Operator('B')
C = Comm(Comm(Comm(A,B),A),B)
D = Comm(Comm(Comm(A,B),B),A)
E = (C-D).expand(commutator=true)
E
>>> [[[A,B],A],B] - [[[A,B],B],A]
```

instead of the expected simpler result `0` (since [[[A,B],A],B] = [[[A,B],B],A]). So how can I force the simpler result without evaluating the commutators (i.e. w/o calling the `doit()` function)? Note that

```
simplify(E.doit())
>>> 0
```

gives the desired result.

Comment: Why is calling `doit()` an issue? Generally SymPy is conservative with automatically simplifying things since simplification can be very costly (and cost is usually hard to predict a priori). EDIT: Or do you want to teach SymPy about the commutator identity?

Comment: @BjoernDahlgren I want to know the answer in the unevaluated context, i.e. I want an commutator expression. Simplification in the unevaluated context should obtain zero for above result.

Comment: I see, from what I can tell [it is not implemented](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/112d6abaf2c777a844d4290db9ecd952053a4a55/sympy/physics/quantum/commutator.py#L121). You may want to open an issue for it.

Comment: @BjoernDahlgren thanks. I would accept that as an answer. I'm not sure I want to raise an issue -- the package seems to have insufficient commutator support for my needs. I want to do some serious nested commutator manipulations using the Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff formula and all I've tried so far with this package was disappointing.

Comment: I have converted the comment to an answer. You are also welcome to add your comments to the issue on github, even if it is just a "wishlist".

Comment: It appears that the specific question was answered but I arrived here looking for documentation on the Sympy QM module and thought I would share two sources I found (since there is almost no documentation for it). JR Johansson has some pages at http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jrjohansson/sympsi-notebooks/tree/master/ with a lot of examples and lectures. Cal Poly has a 2011 paper on doing QM with Sympy at http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1038&context=physsp I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in SymPy, [Commutator._eval_expand_commutator](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/112d6abaf2c777a844d4290db9ecd952053a4a55/sympy/physics/quantum/commutator.py#L121), does not know about this identity so it has to expand the commutators (in the `.doit` method as you have identified) in order to be able to simplify the expression.

What would be needed for this to work, would be to add special case(s) to the `Commutator._eval_expand_commutator` method for when the arguments of a commutator contains commutators, and then check for known identities.

I have opened an issue for this here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10892