# Sympy: substitute to symbolic bosonic commutation its numerical value

Tags: python, physics, sympy, mathematical-expressions, commutativity

I would like to simplify expressions involving boson commutators using sympy. 
The problem is that, using secondquant in sympy, the numerical values of the bosonic commutator [b_0,b^\dagger_0]=1 and [b_0,b^\dagger_1]=0 is never substituted to the symbolic expression.
In other words, I would like SymPy to know about the commutator identity.

The following code

```
from sympy import simplify
from sympy.physics.secondquant import Bd, B 
from sympy.physics.quantum import *
comm1=simplify(Commutator(B(0),Bd(0)).doit())
print(comm1)
comm2=simplify(Commutator(B(0),Bd(1)).doit())
print(comm2)
```

gives

```
comm1= AnnihilateBoson(0)*CreateBoson(0) - CreateBoson(0)*AnnihilateBoson(0)
comm2= AnnihilateBoson(0)*CreateBoson(1) - CreateBoson(1)*AnnihilateBoson(0)
```

instead of the expected values:

```
comm1= 1
comm2= 0
```

I have tried the code mentioned here [How to use sympy.physics.quantum Commutator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095622/how-to-use-sympy-physics-quantum-commutator)

```
comm2=(Commutator(B(0),Bd(0))._eval_expand_commutator()).doit()
print('comm2=',comm2)
```

but this gives the same expression as before

```
comm2= AnnihilateBoson(0)*CreateBoson(0) - CreateBoson(0)*AnnihilateBoson(0)
```

Moreover I have found this related unanswered question:
[Does sympy give me wrong results for the second quantization commutators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227318/does-sympy-give-me-wrong-results-for-the-second-quantization-commutators)

I had a look around line 1682 here:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/physics/secondquant.py
and according to this the commutator should correctly give a Kronecker delta. However, I still get the symbolic expression reported above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by

```
from sympy.physics.quantum import *
```

This code gives the expected behaviour

```
from sympy.physics.secondquant import *
from sympy import symbols
a, b = symbols('a,b')
c = Commutator(B(a),Bd(a))
print(c.doit())
```